# jQuery .ajax not communicating with host

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I've had no luck finding an answer to what I thought would be a simple problem.

I am writing a webapp jQuery routine to grab data from a php program on a host server.

(My test code is from a sample I found on the internet, but never got working.)

If I type the URL into my browser the php works fine.  However, when I try to make the `$.ajax` call, the error routine is called with no meaningful error code.

> (text_status = 'Error' and strError is blank).

Note: cloudResult is the div id of my html.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

javascript (called in response to a button click):

```
function cloudConnect(e) {
    var term = {
        button: e
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.hrosenthal.com/reply.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: term,
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
            //alert("no connection");
            $("#cloudResult").html("")
            $("#cloudResult").append("no connection: " + text_status + " " + strError)
        },
        timeout: 60000,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#cloudResult").html("");
            for (var i in data) {
                $("#cloudResult").append("<li>" + data[i] + "</li>");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

php:

```
<?php
$choice =$_POST["button"];
$cars = array("Honde", "BMW" , "Ferrari");
$bikes = array("Ducaite", "Royal Enfield" , "Harley Davidson");
if($choice == "cars") print json_encode($cars);
else print json_encode($bikes);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like the URL you're using for your AJAX call might be on a different domain, if that's the case then you need to use JSONP to do cross-domain requests. If you are hosting the front-end and back-end code on the same domain, make sure the `www` is being used in both places, if not this is a different domain.

Comment: Is http://www.hrosenthal.com is in your domain?

Comment: Thank you,  I had not been aware of the cross domain issue.  Although I got it working, I ran into a problem with the PHP $_POST command.  Although I post in the ajax call, php $_POST doesn't retrieve the arguments, however $_GET does.  I know that sounds correct, but I though $_POST retrieved POSTS and $_GET retrieved GETS.  Thanks again

Comment: Feel free to provide your own answer and accept it!